SecurityException: Starting FGS with type mediaProjection (Android 14)
Since targeting SDK 34 (Android 14), I've seen a few crashes on Android 14 (though small minority of Android 14 users):
java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type mediaProjection callerApp=ProcessRecord{44a8006 6938:com.foo/u0a6} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT, android:project_media] 
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:7214)
       at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:775)
       at com.foo.FooService.onStartCommand(FooService.java:28)

So far, only on Galaxy A13 & A72.
What could be causing this?

Are you using the media projection APIs, directly or via a third-party library?

using the APIs directly

Do you request the permissions cited in the error?

I have the FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION in the manifest uses-permission. If I was missing something, I don't think it could work on most other Android 14 devices, right?

You do not hold some permission, based on the error. Whether that is because you're not requesting it or the user denied it, I cannot say.

It's probably some edge case. For example, I've seen it's possible to have two media projection system prompts on top of each other. So perhaps if the user allows one and cancels the other, can lead to strange situations. I'll investigate further. Thanks.

I faced this issue too, so, to resolve it, first I added the following permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />

then I had to add this permission and label it as signature permission:
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"   
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" 
/>


Thanks for that. Do you have any reference to why this might help?

Consider calling createScreenCaptureIntent()  before you invoke startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION).
MediaProjectionManager mgr = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
startActivityForResult(mgr.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);

Calling createScreenCaptureIntent() shows permission notification to the user, so the user must grant the permission before you can create the service.
Media projection
